# _dateparsefailure when the date already has a match

Tags: logstash, date-parsing

I'm trying to config logstash to process some test log, but I keep getting a dateparsefailure and I don't understand why. My input is

```
2016-09-18 00:00:02,013 UTC, idf="639b26a731284b43beac8b26f829bcab"
```

And my config (I've also tried including the timezone into the pattern):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/test.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  date {
        match => ["message", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        timezone => "UTC"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second},%{NUMBER:milis} UTC, idf=\"%{WORD:idf}\""}
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Finaly, the error:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-09-21T10:04:32.060000+0000", :message=>"Failed parsing date from field", :field=>"message", :value=>"2016-09-18 00:00:02,013 UTC, idf=\"639b26a731284b43beac8b26f829bcab\"", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"2016-09-18 00:00:02,013 UTC, idf=\"639b26a731284b4...\" is malformed at \" UTC, idf=\"639b26a731284b4...\"", :config_parsers=>"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn, :file=>"logstash/filters/date.rb", :line=>"354", :method=>"filter"}
```

It says that the date it is malformed after the end of it. Why does this happen, shouldn't it 'stop searching' since the date has already a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can use the `date` filter, you first have to use `grok` to separate the date and the rest of the message. The `date` filter only accepts a timestamp. If you have any other information in the field the error you are describing will occur.

Using your provided logline I would recommend this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timedate} %{GREEDYDATA}"}
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timedate" => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    }
}
```

In this minimal example I match the timestamp in the `timedate` field and then crunch it trough the date filter.

Comment: This is correct. match => ["timedate" => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]

Comment: @FallAndLearn Fixed the typo, thanks for the heads up